# How to generate random numbers using C# that hasn't been listed in a database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, random

I'm working on an application that allows me to generate random ID numbers (6 integers) for employees but I would like to know how to generate these random numbers using C# and not duplicate the numbers that has been already used by another employee in the SQL database. Below is the code done in SQL:

```
declare @unique_UID varchar(6)

select @unique_UID = Right(ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)), 6)

while exists (select 1 from dbo.tblUserID 

   where @unique_UID = UserID_UID 
         and len(@unique_uid) = 6
         and @unique_UID <> @parm_User_Pin)(
         select @unique_UID = Right(ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)), 6)
```

`

Comment: why not just make it a primary key and let sql deal with it automatically

Comment: When you have a multi-user database you need to create a a SQL built-in function to guarantee unique Primary Key.

Comment: You better keep it on the sql level. Moving it to the c# code would require a round trip to the sql for each generated number just to test if it already exists in the database.

Comment: Generating and checking can get inefficient as the number of IDs grows.  I haven't  tried this but what about creating the enumerable range of all possible numbers and excluding the ones that exist.  Then select a random one from what remains.

Comment: Do you rather mean 'arbitrary'? In which case do what @nycdan suggests: as a one-time exercise, generate a 'large' table of numbers then allocate them when required e.g. database proc to return the next available number while marking it as allocated. (Rule of thumb for databases: query, don't calculate.) If you truly mean 'random', please elaborate.

Comment: Just use an auto-increment identity column, or, if that is not appropriate, use a GUID.  Trying to guarantee uniqueness of completely random is not trivial, especially when you consider that you are creating a race condition where you could select a number, check, find it doesn't exist, another user could get the same number, check, find it doesn't exist because the first user hadn't written to the database yet, and then end up with duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

6 integeres make 999999 numbers. Just write them all the available ones in a table. Then pick one randomly and delete it:

```
  WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP (1) number
    FROM available
    ORDER BY NEWID()
  )
  DELETE FROM cte
  OUTPUT DELETED.number;
```

This is more reliable than trying to generate random and check availability. If your org has 999998 employees already, trying to randomly generate the one still available is going to take ages...

Comment: the approach is right but the question specified random, which you can still do from the set of available numbers.  No need to change the question parameters.

Comment: It is random. `... TOP (1) .. ORDER BY NEWID()` means random.

Comment: You could even use a ['numbers table'](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) and OUTER JOIN with emplyees, filter out the ones that match then TOP(1) random order, to eliminate the need to materialize/maintain all unused numbers.

Comment: Thanks.  I missed the NewID.  Good approach and supports multi-client well.